# How to access per-face UV assignment via API

Tags: python, uv

In Blender 2.79, how can I find the per-face UV image associated with a given face? Essentially what I want to do is this (pseudocode):

```py
for face in mesh:
  if face.uv_image == "some_image.png":
      do something
  else:
      do something_else
```

Comment: Dont think images are assigned on a per face basis. Look at the python operator mesh uv template in text editor.

Comment: It's a fairly antiquated feature but it does exist. Generally Blender refers to per-face images as "TexFace"

Answer (score 1):

Found it. This code prints the name of the TexFace image for each face of the mesh:

```py
import bpy

object = bpy.context.object
mesh = object.data

for face in mesh.uv_textures['UVMap'].data:
    print(face.image.name)
```